# Find a correct trial function for undetermined coefficients.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the DE

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}  + 2y = xe^{-x}$$

Is this solvable by method of undetermined coefficients? If so, how do I find a correct trial function for it?

Comment: I would personally use [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) to avoid having to guess the form of the particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the homegeneous equation and try to find a particular of the form
$$
y=Axe^{-x}+Be^{-x}.
$$
This equation can be solved easier using integrating factors.

Comment: Interesting that the trial function emulates the derivative of the RHS of the original equation.

Comment: @HaydenJulius they tend to.  You generally start with the right hand side, and the various derivatives of the RHS.  Sometimes you need to be more creative.

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^{-x}$ is not found in as part of the solution to:

$\frac {dy}{dx} + 2y = 0$

Then $y = A xe^{-x} + B e^{-x}$ would be the right place to start.  But if you had

$\frac {dy}{dx} + y = xe^{-x}$

It would and you would want to try $y = A x^2e^{-x} + Bx e^{-x}$